# Почему количество страниц в разделе "Покрытие" не соотвествует "Основные интернет-показатели" в Google Search Console?

Tags: seo, index, google-search

У инструмента `Google Search Console` в разделе покрытия показывает около 1.15 тысяч страниц, а на странице "Основные интернет-показатели" всего 66. Сайту уже более пяти лет. Примерно с начала апреля поменял ссылки в sitemap с http на https. До этого примерно такая ситуация была. Вопрос, нормально ли это? И если нет, как изменить ситуацию либо в какую сторону смотреть.

[image: Покрытие]
[image: Основные интернет-показатели]

Comment: Возможно, мало посещений на страницы

Answer (score 0):

Надо проверить все ли решено с **https://**
Все файлы sitemap
Все URL в файлах sitemap

Проверить есть ли тег **Canonical**. Если есть, то какой там URL прописан

**Дополнительно**
Возможно что-то поменялось в Robots.txt и произошел запрет на сканирование
Проверить Robots Meta Tag, чтобы там тоже не было запрета

**Еще**
На первом скрине есть вкладка "Исключено" там может быть тоже инфо, что пошло не так

Причин может быть масса

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 1. Все файлы sitemap Все URL в файлах sitemap - да. 2. Все есть в Canonical и корректно. Robot - исключено пару страниц.В "исключено" большинство страниц показывает как не проиндексировано, но обнаружено. Но такой статус достаточно долго уже